# MSW Expect API Error with testing library fail assertion

Tags: react-native, rtk-query, msw, react-native-testing-library

I'm trying to test a failure on my API call with MSW, testing library and RTK Query. More on the context: I'm testing a hook and I'm calling a function and expect an API fail to assert that an error callback is call.

This is the code, the test call the check auth function and then pass in `authenticateUser` and then the api fail as expected (see test file):

**Code**

```js
const checkAuth = useCallback(async () => {
    const token = await checkToken();

    if (!isAuthenticated && token) {
      await authenticateUser(token);
    } else {
      dispatch(clearAuth);
      onAuthFailureCallback?.();
    }
  }, [
    isAuthenticated,
    authenticateUser,
    checkToken,
    dispatch,
    onAuthFailureCallback,
  ]);

const authenticateUser = useCallback(
    async (token: string) => {
      try {
        await startAuthenticate(token, false).unwrap();
        onAuthSuccessCallback?.();
      } catch (err) {
        onAuthFailureCallback?.(err);
      }
    },
    [startAuthenticate, onAuthSuccessCallback, onAuthFailureCallback],
  );
```

**Test**

```js
it('given the user is not authenticated and the authentication fail an error should be sent back', async () => {
      server.use(
        rest.get(`${API_BASE_URL}api/v2.1/session`, (req, res, ctx) => {
          ctx.set('Authorization', 'Bearer token');
          return res(
            ctx.status(401),
            ctx.json({
              message: 'Could not be identified',
            }),
          );
        }),
      );

      jest
        .spyOn(sessionStorageUtils, 'getUserToken')
        .mockResolvedValue('my token');

      const appStore = createStore({
        preloadedState: {
          session: { ...sessionStateMock, isAuthenticated: false },
        },
      });

      const { result } = renderHook(useAuth, {
        initialProps: {
          onAuthFailureCallback: onAuthFailureCallbackMock,
          onAuthSuccessCallback: onAuthSuccessCallbackkMock,
        },
        wrapper: props => <HookWrapper {...props} appStore={appStore} />,
      });

      await act(async () => {
        await result.current.checkAuth();
      });

      expect.assertions(1);
      return expect(onAuthFailureCallbackMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        status: 401,
        data: { message: 'Could not be identified' },
      });
    });
  });
```

The assertion work fine but jest still throw the api error and make the test fail

**Jest error**

```js
thrown: Object {
  "error": Object {
  "data": Object {
    "message": "Could not be identified",
  },
  "status": 401,
  },
...
}
```

Did you have an idea how to make the test pass and make jest not yield on api error?

- I've try to use **try / catch** in my test file
- I've try to use the specific jest assertion `expect.rejects`

Comment: Are you sure it's a jest error and not something else, like the application logging an error?  If I remember jest usually raises language like "uncaught error".  Can you induce a similar error (like disabling the network or deliberately giving a bad URL) and convince yourself you do not get a similar message?